# Custom serialiser with object factory

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++14, serialization

A couple of years ago I wrote a serialisation library for my project. By the time it worked well, but recently I thought it could be modernised. Back then I needed something that looks similar to Boost's serialiser, but also support polymorphism. I need to serialise and deserialise different types of objects from the same inheriting tree. However I didn't wanted to include Boost library just for this. Also I needed to support different sources besides `FILE*` (I only included just one here.)

I came across with [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/495191/Serialization-implementation-in-Cplusplus), tweaked a bit, wrote a couple of tests around it, and been using. It's spread across multiple files [in my repo](https://github.com/industrial-revolutioners/Grafkit2/tree/master/src/framework/utils/persistence), and I do have a [couple more tests](https://github.com/industrial-revolutioners/Grafkit2/blob/master/tests/test_utils/test_persistence.cpp) for it using GTest.

My overall questions are

- How can I use std some more to make it more compatible with its containers? I think about supporting `std::map` first
- What other possible way are there to improve the way I define and store factories of the different objects?
- The most important thing is for me is support more efficiently the serialisation of the parents of the class instances. At this point I only have a terrible solution that is I define a non-virtual `_Serialize()` method that takes care of it via override. Is there a solution to collect all the parents serialiser method more seamlessly and invoke them?

Here's the source code, that I had concatenated together and modified a bit to work single handed. I used clang on MacOS via Cmake to test it.

```
/*
    Dynamics API
*/

#ifndef __DYNAMICS_H__
#define __DYNAMICS_H__

#include <string>
#include <map>


namespace Grafkit
{
class Clonables;

/**
    */
class Clonable
{
    friend class Clonables;

public:
    virtual ~Clonable() = default;
    virtual Clonable *CreateObj() const = 0;
};

/**
    */
class Clonables
{
    std::map<std::string, const Clonable *> m_clonables;

    Clonables() {}

    Clonables(const Clonables &) = delete;
    Clonables &operator=(const Clonables &) = delete;

    virtual ~Clonables()
    {
        for (auto it = m_clonables.begin(); it != m_clonables.end(); ++it)
        {
            const Clonable *clone = it->second;
            delete clone;
        }
        m_clonables.clear();
    }

public:
    static Clonables &Instance()
    {
        static Clonables instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void AddClonable(const char *CLASS_NAME, Clonable *clone)
    {
        std::string name = CLASS_NAME;

        auto it = m_clonables.find(name);
        if (it == m_clonables.end())
        {
            m_clonables[name] = clone;
        }
    }

    const Clonable *Find(const char *CLASS_NAME)
    {
        std::string name = CLASS_NAME;
        auto it = m_clonables.find(name);
        if (it == m_clonables.end())
            return nullptr;
        const Clonable *clone = it->second;
        return clone;
    }

    Clonable *Create(const char *CLASS_NAME)
    {
        const Clonable *clone = Find(CLASS_NAME);
        if (clone)
            return clone->CreateObj();

        return nullptr;
    }
};

class AddClonable
{
public:
    AddClonable(const char *CLASS_NAME, Clonable *clone)
    {
        Clonables::Instance().AddClonable(CLASS_NAME, clone);
    }
};

} // namespace Grafkit

#define CLONEABLE_DECL(CLASS_NAME)                        \
public:                                                 \
    virtual Grafkit::Clonable *CreateObj() const override \
    {                                                     \
        return new CLASS_NAME();                          \
    }

#define CLONEABLE_FACTORY_DECL(CLASS_NAME)           \
    CLONEABLE_DECL(CLASS_NAME)                       \
public:                                            \
    class Factory : public Grafkit::Clonable         \
    {                                                \
    public:                                        \
        virtual Grafkit::Clonable *CreateObj() const \
        {                                            \
            return new CLASS_NAME();                 \
        }                                            \
    };                                               \
                                                    \
private:                                           \
    static Grafkit::AddClonable _addClonableFactory;

#define CLONEABLE_FACTORY_IMPL(CLASS_NAME) \
    Grafkit::AddClonable CLASS_NAME::_addClonableFactory(#CLASS_NAME, new CLASS_NAME::Factory());

#define CLONEABLE_FACTORY_LOCAL_IMPL(CLASS_NAME) \
    Grafkit::AddClonable CLASS_NAME##_addClonableFactory(#CLASS_NAME, new CLASS_NAME::Factory());

#endif //__DYNAMICS_H__

/*
Persistence API
*/

#ifndef __PERSISTENCE_H__
#define __PERSISTENCE_H__

#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

// Alrady included above
//#include "dynamics.h"

namespace Grafkit
{
class Archive;

class Persistent : public Clonable
{
public:
    Persistent() {}
    virtual ~Persistent() {}

    static Persistent *Load(Archive &ar);
    template <class C>
    static C *LoadT(Archive &ar) { return dynamic_cast<C *>(Load(ar)); }
    void Store(Archive &ar);

protected:
    virtual void Serialize(Archive &ar) = 0;

    virtual std::string GetClazzName() const = 0;
    virtual int GetVersion() const { return 0; }
};

class Archive
{
public:
    explicit Archive(int IsStoring = 0);
    virtual ~Archive();

    /* IO API */
protected:
    virtual void Write(const void *buffer, size_t length) = 0;
    virtual void Read(void *buffer, size_t length) = 0;

    size_t WriteString(const char *input);
    size_t ReadString(char *&output);

public:
    template <typename T>
    void PersistField(T &t)
    {
        if (m_isStoring)
        {
            Write(&t, sizeof(T));
        }
        else
        {
            Read(&t, sizeof(T));
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    void PersistVector(T *&v, uint32_t &count)
    {
        if (m_isStoring)
        {
            Write(&count, sizeof(count));
            Write(v, sizeof(T) * count);
        }
        else
        {
            uint32_t readCount = 0;
            Read(&readCount, sizeof(readCount));

            void *p = malloc(sizeof(T) * readCount);
            Read(p, sizeof(T) * readCount);

            v = reinterpret_cast<T *>(p);

            count = readCount;
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    void PersistStdVector(std::vector<T> &v)
    {
        if (m_isStoring)
        {
            uint32_t u32count = v.size(); //clamp it down to 32 bit
            Write(&u32count, sizeof(u32count));
            void *p = v.data();
            Write(p, sizeof(T) * u32count);
        }
        else
        {
            uint32_t count = 0;
            Read(&count, sizeof(count));

            void *p = malloc(sizeof(T) * count);
            Read(p, sizeof(T) * count);

            v.clear();
            v.assign(static_cast<T *>(p), static_cast<T *>(p) + count);
        }
    }

    void PersistString(const char *&str);
    void PersistString(std::string &str);

    void StoreObject(Persistent *object);
    Persistent *LoadObject();

    int IsStoring() const { return m_isStoring; }
    void SetDirection(bool IsStoring) { m_isStoring = IsStoring; }

private:
    int m_isStoring;
};
} // namespace Grafkit

// ------------------

#define PERSISTENT_DECL(CLASS_NAME, VERSION_NO) \
public:                                       \
    CLONEABLE_FACTORY_DECL(CLASS_NAME)          \
public:                                       \
    std::string GetClazzName() const override   \
    {                                           \
        return #CLASS_NAME;                     \
    }                                           \
    int GetVersion() const override             \
    {                                           \
        return VERSION_NO;                      \
    }

#define PERSISTENT_IMPL(CLASS_NAME) \
    CLONEABLE_FACTORY_IMPL(CLASS_NAME)

// ---

#define PERSIST_FIELD(AR, FIELD) (AR.PersistField<decltype(FIELD)>((FIELD)))
#define PERSIST_VECTOR(AR, VECTOR, COUNT) (AR.PersistVector<std::remove_pointer<decltype(VECTOR)>::type>(VECTOR, COUNT))
#define PERSIST_STD_VECTOR(AR, VECTOR) (AR.PersistStdVector<decltype(VECTOR)::value_type>(VECTOR))
#define PERSIST_STRING(AR, FIELD) (AR.PersistString((FIELD)))

#define _PERSIST_OBJECT(AR, TYPE, IN_FIELD, OUT_FIELD)              \
    {                                                               \
        if (AR.IsStoring())                                         \
        {                                                           \
            AR.StoreObject(dynamic_cast<Persistent *>((IN_FIELD))); \
        }                                                           \
        else                                                        \
        {                                                           \
            (OUT_FIELD) = dynamic_cast<TYPE>(AR.LoadObject());      \
        }                                                           \
    }

#define PERSIST_OBJECT(AR, OBJECT) _PERSIST_OBJECT(AR, decltype(OBJECT), OBJECT, OBJECT)
#define PERSIST_REFOBJECT(AR, REF) _PERSIST_OBJECT(AR, decltype(REF.Get()), REF.Get(), REF)

#endif //__PERSISTENCE_H__

/*
    Archive IO layer
*/

#ifndef __ARCHIVE_H__
#define __ARCHIVE_H__

// #include "persistence.h"

namespace Grafkit
{

class ArchiveFile : public Archive
{
public:
    ArchiveFile(FILE *stream, bool IsStoring = false);
    virtual ~ArchiveFile();

    void Write(const void *buffer, size_t length) override;
    void Read(void *buffer, size_t length) override;

private:
    FILE *_stream;
};
}; // namespace Grafkit

#endif //__ARCHIVE_H__

/***************************************************
    Impl
****************************************************/

/*
    Persistent layer impl: persistent.cpp
*/

#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

// Already pasted above
//#include "persistence.h"
//#include "dynamics.h"

using namespace Grafkit;
using namespace std;

void Persistent::Store(Archive &ar)
{
    string CLASS_NAME = this->GetClazzName();
    uint8_t ver = this->GetVersion();

    PERSIST_STRING(ar, CLASS_NAME);
    PERSIST_FIELD(ar, ver);

    this->Serialize(ar);
}

Persistent *Persistent::Load(Archive &ar)
{
    string CLASS_NAME;
    uint8_t ver = 0;
    PERSIST_STRING(ar, CLASS_NAME);

    Clonable *clone = Clonables::Instance().Create(CLASS_NAME.c_str());
    assert(clone);

    Persistent *obj = dynamic_cast<Persistent *>(clone);
    assert(obj);

    PERSIST_FIELD(ar, ver);
    assert(ver == obj->GetVersion());

    obj->Serialize(ar);
    return obj;
}

/**
    Archive
*/

Archive::Archive(int IsStoring) : m_isStoring(IsStoring)
{
}

Archive::~Archive()
{
}

size_t Archive::WriteString(const char *input)
{
    uint16_t slen = strlen(input);
    this->Write(&slen, sizeof(slen));
    this->Write(input, slen + 1);
    return slen;
}

size_t Archive::ReadString(char *&output)
{
    uint16_t slen = 0;
    this->Read(&slen, sizeof(slen));
    output = new char[slen + 1];
    this->Read(output, slen + 1);
    return slen;
}

void Archive::PersistString(const char *&str)
{
    if (m_isStoring)
    {
        WriteString(str);
    }
    else
    {
        char *in = nullptr;
        ReadString(in);
        str = in;
    }
}

void Archive::PersistString(string &str)
{
    if (m_isStoring)
    {
        WriteString(str.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        char *in = nullptr;
        ReadString(in);
        str = in;
        delete[] in;
    }
}

void Archive::StoreObject(Persistent *object)
{
    uint8_t isNotNull = object != nullptr;
    PersistField(isNotNull);

    if (isNotNull)
        object->Store(*this);
}

Persistent *Archive::LoadObject()
{
    uint8_t isNotNull = 0;
    PersistField(isNotNull);

    if (isNotNull)
        return Persistent::Load(*this);
    return nullptr;
}

/*
    Archive IO impl: archive.cpp
*/

// Already included above
// #include "archive.h"
#include <cassert>

using namespace Grafkit;

ArchiveFile::ArchiveFile(FILE *stream, bool IsStoring) : Archive(IsStoring),
                                                        _stream(stream)
{
    assert(_stream);
}

ArchiveFile::~ArchiveFile()
{
}

void ArchiveFile::Write(const void *buffer, size_t length)
{
    assert(_stream);
    fwrite(buffer, length, 1, this->_stream);
}

void ArchiveFile::Read(void *buffer, size_t length)
{
    assert(_stream);
    fread(buffer, length, 1, this->_stream);
}

/**
    Test classes, Main
*/

class SimpleClass : public Grafkit::Persistent
{
public:
    SimpleClass() : Persistent(), m_i(0)
    {
    }

    void SetParams(const int i, const std::string str)
    {
        m_i = i;
        m_str = str;
    }

    int GetI() const { return m_i; }
    std::string GetStr() const { return m_str; }

    PERSISTENT_DECL(SimpleClass, 1);

protected:
    void Serialize(Archive &ar) override
    {
        PERSIST_FIELD(ar, m_i);
        PERSIST_STRING(ar, m_str);
    }

private:
    int m_i;
    std::string m_str;
};

class SimpleBaseClass : public Grafkit::Persistent
{
public:
    SimpleBaseClass() : Persistent(), m_i(0) {}

    void SetParams(const int i, const std::string str)
    {
        m_i = i;
        m_str = str;
    }

    int GetI() const { return m_i; }
    std::string GetStr() const { return m_str; }

    virtual std::string GetSomeIntern() const = 0;

protected:
    void _Serialize(Archive &ar)
    {
        PERSIST_FIELD(ar, m_i);
        PERSIST_STRING(ar, m_str);
    }

private:
    int m_i;
    std::string m_str;
};

class DerivedClassA : public SimpleBaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClassA() : SimpleBaseClass(), m_str1("This is derived class A") {}
    virtual std::string GetSomeIntern() const override { return m_str1; }

    PERSISTENT_DECL(DerivedClassA, 1);

protected:
    void Serialize(Archive &ar) override
    {
        SimpleBaseClass::_Serialize(ar);
        PERSIST_STRING(ar, m_str1);
    }

private:
    std::string m_str1;
};

class DerivedClassB : public SimpleBaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClassB() : SimpleBaseClass(), m_str2("This is derived class B") {}
    virtual std::string GetSomeIntern() const override { return m_str2; }

    PERSISTENT_DECL(DerivedClassB, 1);

protected:
    void Serialize(Archive &ar) override
    {
        SimpleBaseClass::_Serialize(ar);
        PERSIST_STRING(ar, m_str2);
    }

private:
    std::string m_str2;
};

#include <cstdio>

PERSISTENT_IMPL(SimpleClass);
PERSISTENT_IMPL(DerivedClassA);
PERSISTENT_IMPL(DerivedClassB);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;

    // -- 1. simple class
    // given
    SimpleClass *simpleObj = new SimpleClass();
    simpleObj->SetParams(42, "Hello Serializer");

    SimpleBaseClass *inheritedA = new DerivedClassA();
    SimpleBaseClass *inheritedB = new DerivedClassB();

    inheritedA->SetParams(314, "Hello Serializer w/ inherited classes");
    inheritedA->SetParams(216, "Hello Serializer GLEJD");

    // when
    fp = fopen("archive.bin", "wb'");
    assert(fp);

    ArchiveFile arWrite(fp, true);
    simpleObj->Store(arWrite);
    inheritedA->Store(arWrite);
    inheritedB->Store(arWrite);

    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = nullptr;

    // then
    fp = fopen("archive.bin", "rb");
    assert(fp);

    ArchiveFile arRead(fp, false);
    SimpleClass *loadedObj = Persistent::LoadT<SimpleClass>(arRead);
    SimpleBaseClass *loadedA = Persistent::LoadT<SimpleBaseClass>(arRead);
    SimpleBaseClass *loadedB = Persistent::LoadT<SimpleBaseClass>(arRead);

    assert(loadedObj);
    assert(simpleObj->GetI() == loadedObj->GetI());
    assert(simpleObj->GetStr().compare(loadedObj->GetStr()) == 0);

    assert(loadedA);
    assert(dynamic_cast<DerivedClassA *>(loadedA));
    assert(inheritedA->GetI() == loadedA->GetI());
    assert(inheritedA->GetStr().compare(loadedA->GetStr()) == 0);
    assert(inheritedA->GetSomeIntern().compare(loadedA->GetSomeIntern()) == 0); 

    assert(loadedB);
    assert(dynamic_cast<DerivedClassB *>(loadedB));
    assert(inheritedB->GetI() == loadedB->GetI());
    assert(inheritedB->GetStr().compare(loadedB->GetStr()) == 0);
    assert(inheritedB->GetSomeIntern().compare(loadedB->GetSomeIntern()) == 0); 

    fclose(fp);

    delete simpleObj;
    delete inheritedA;
    delete inheritedB;

    delete loadedObj;
    delete loadedA;
    delete loadedB;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `Cloneables`? It is singleton map wrapper, but creates objects through `Clonable::CreateObj` which does not appear to do cloning. It would make sense in `Factory` which I guess is there for de-serialization to create empty/default objects before filling them, but you should really **describe how is it supposed to work**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions.

- `__DYNAMICS_H__` is a reserved identifier because it contains consecutive underscores.  Use a non-reserved identifier like `DYNAMICS_H_`.  Also, this name is too common and may introduce name clashes.  One solution is to append a sequence of random characters.
- I see no reason to make `Clonables` a friend of `Clonable`.  The latter doesn't have anything private.
- Your `Clonables::m_clonables` owns the objects, so it should use `std::unique_ptr` instead of plain pointers.  This way, you don't need to care about the copy operations, move operations, or destructors.  The default constructor is also redundant.  Also, I don't see why you make the destructor of `Cloneables` private.
- `Instance` is effectively a global variable.  Global variables are generally discouraged in C++.  They should belong to the place where they are used.
- `AddClonable` should take a `std::string_view` or, in C++14, take a `std::string` by value and move it into the operation.  ALL-CAPS names are usually used for macros.  And `clone` should be `const Clonable*`.  First performing a `find` and then do `[]` is wasteful.  Use `emplace`:

  ```
  void AddClonable(std::string name, const Clonable* clone)
  {
      m_clonables.emplace(std::move(name), clone);
  }
  ```
- In `Find`, the variable `clone` isn't really necessary.  The extra copy is avoidable in C++14 by using a template:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  const Clonable* Find(const T& name)
  {
      auto it = m_clonables.find(name);
      if (it == m_clonables.end())
          return nullptr;
      else
          return it->second;
  }
  ```

  `Create` is similar.
- The `AddClonable` class feels questionable from a design perspective.

These should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, Sine then I've improved this one a lot.
- I use `#pragma once` for guarding
- `Clonables` had been merged into `Persistence`
- Properties / behavior of `Clonable` had been merged into `Serializable`
- Instead of storing *prototpye* objects, I use `std::function` as a virtual factory to reduce footprint and side effects
- I also added [this](https://github.com/voidah/archive/blob/master/archive.h) to implement the rest of the serialization
- The complete single-header soluiton is [here](https://github.com/industrial-revolutioners/Grafkit/blob/master/src/grafkit/utils/archive.h)

Answer (score 0):

I started reading.

IMO `Find` should be private and const.

Once you have done this you can replace the map  
with a map of std::string, unique_ptr.

Doing so you get rid of the destructor of Clonables.

Does this make sense?

Comment: It would make sense if you elaborated on object ownership (and the lack of it in the code provided) and provide alternative solution using [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). `Find` could still be useful, but should not return raw pointer (describe why). Solution is up to you, but it should probably take inspiration in [map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) as `Clonables` is essentialy singleton wrapper of a map.